# PHP APC get and set value atomically

Tags: php, apc

Is it possible to do this in the atomic way?

```
$myvalue = apc_get("mykey");
apc_store("mykey",0);
// log/deal with myvalue
```

"mykey" is increasing on other process frequently, and I don't want to miss count them.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. It looks like you always want to set it to zero. If so then why even store it?

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is [apc_cas()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-cas.php).  The 'cas' stands for 'compare and swap'.  It will save a value in the cache, but only if it hasn't changed since you last fetched it.  If the function fails, you just re-fetch the cached value and try to save it again.  This ensures no changes are skipped.

Let's say you want to atomically increment a counter.  The technique would be:

```
apc_add('counter', 0); // set counter to zero, only if it does not already exist.    
$oldVar = apc_fetch('counter'); // get current counter

// do whatever you need to do with the counter ...

// ... when you are ready to increment it you can do this
while ( apc_cas('counter', $oldVar, intval($oldVar)+1) === false ) {
    // huh.  Someone else must have updated the counter while we were busy.
    // Fetch the current value, then try to increment it again.
    $oldVar = apc_fetch('counter');
}
```

It just so happens that APC provides specialized incrementer and decrementer for this, [apc_inc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-inc.php) and [apc_dec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-dec.php).

Memcache has a [cas()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.cas.php) that also works with non-integer values.

Comment: Your answer is misleading. apc_cas doesn't work with anything but integers.

Comment: After reading the docs, you're totally right.  I was thinking of memcache's `cas()` function, which is good for any value although the function signature is a little different.  Fixing post...